# Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null during dynamic creation of textarea from JSON Object using CKeditor in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

**Inside Html File**

```
<textarea type="text" style="width: 100%;" rows="25" cols="40" name="requirements ng-model="data" options="ckEditorOptions">
</textarea>
```

When I paste the above code in html it does not show any error and I'm able to get the editor. But if I write the same code in js file and using compile to render it to html it throws an error [image]

**Inside JS File**

```
$scope.view = '<textarea type="text" style="width: 100%;" rows="25" cols="40" name="requirements ng-model="data" options="ckEditorOptions">';

Using Compile in HTML file
<p compile="view"></p>
```

As far as I know Object is not getting created due to which it gives an error. Even though I have included ckeditor.js

As I'm new to CKeditor I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: @Zooly I've added the code please check.

Comment: Did you try existing directives? https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntaxt in

```
$scope.view = '<textarea type="text" style="width: 100%;" rows="25" cols="40" name="requirements ng-model="data" options="ckEditorOptions">';
```

I think there is a typo, and what you wanted was actually

```
$scope.view = '<textarea type="text" style="width: 100%;" rows="25" cols="40" name="requirements" ng-model="data" options="ckEditorOptions">';
```

It seams to me the **ng-model** attribute was never declared, since you had a syntax problem in the declaration of the **name** attribute.